Finding a specific reference on the construction of a confidence interval where by inspection we can see it does contain the parameter
I realise this is a long shot but I am trying to find a reference to a specific example of a construction of a confidence interval which I came across in the past. My memory on this is hazy and I may be misremembering things.
The overall point of this example was that with a specific realisation of a X% confidence interval, you cannot say there is an X% probability that the parameter is in this specific interval - and in fact by inspection of the interval after constructing it (at least in some cases) we could actually be certain that it did (or did not) contain the parameter.
The construction was something like as follows:

Draw two points $a,b$ uniformly from $(\theta - 1,\theta +1)$.
Then $(min(a,b),max(a,b))$ is a 50% confidence interval for $\theta$
Then there was something like, if the distance between $a$ and $b$ was greater than 1,  we could guarantee the interval contained $\theta$ and we could do this without knowing what $\theta$ was.

Do you know the example I am trying to remember and if so, where is it from?
I am aware of other examples of a similar nature, for example from MacKay's text (see answer here). I had a quick look at a work by Jaynes related to this topic and could not find it in there.
I could piece together examples myself, but I seem to recall there was something I found compelling about the example I am describing above such that I thought it would be a good choice to use for education/teaching.
Edit
This question is not a duplicate of this because I am not asking what is a confidence interval. I am asking for help finding a reference to a paper/textbook/lecture notes which I read but have forgotten, which contained the example I am trying to describe above, so that I can remind myself of all the details and cite the source. I acknowledge it is similar to the example of accepted answer in the link above.
I know it is a long shot that someone on here will remember the same example and if the question being too narrow is reason to close it then fair enough, but it is absolutely not a duplicate of the question above.

The example you seek is a variation of the Welch (1939) example (see reference and example explanation in the Problems section of the Wikipedia entry for Confidence Interval.  It is a so-called  'counterexample' to Neyman's original theory of confidence intervals. In the modern CI approach, this example is viewed as an example to remind people that there are some occasions when conditional confidence intervals are preferred over unconditional confidence intervals. It can be a useful teaching aid.
